# Networkx spread nodes and shorten lables

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I have a networks bipartite graph.
this is the code:

```
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(USsNames, bipartite=0) # Add the node attribute "bipartite"
    G.add_nodes_from(TCsNames, bipartite=1)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(compoundArr)

    labeldict = {}


    # Separate by group
    pos = {}

    # Update position for node from each group
    pos.update({node: [1, index] for index, node in enumerate(USsNames)})
    pos.update({node: [2, index] for index, node in enumerate(TCsNames)})

    nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=10,with_labels=False)
    for p in pos:  # raise text positions
        pos[p][1] += 0.12

    # create the dictionary with the formatted labels
    edge_labels = {i[0:2]:'{0:.2f}'.format(i[2]['weight']) for i in G.edges(data=True)}

    # add the custom egde labels
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels,font_size=8)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos,font_size=8)
    plt.show()
```

And the output:
[image]

I need to spread the left nodes so they will spread up, and to shorten the right nodes labels (let's say first four chars).

I tried to find a solution but I didn't make it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reconstructed your case on the generated example data.

Firstly we have this graph.

[image]

The size of the left array is far less than the size of the right array so the left array is drawn non-proportionally. To draw it properly, you should modify your position update function:

`pos.update({node: [1, index] for index, node in enumerate(USsNames)})`

We know that `TCsNames` is larger than `USsNames` so we can multiply every `USsNames` nodes Y-position to their ratio:

`pos.update({node: [1, index*(len(TCsNames)/len(USsNames))] for index, node in enumerate(USsNames)})`

Now we have this graph:

[image]

To crop nodes labels, you should modify your `draw_networkx_labels` with the `labels` parameter:

`nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels=node_labels, font_size=8)`

with `node_labels` equal to:

`node_labels = {i: i[:5] for i in G.nodes}` (5 is the desired node label length).

And finally we have the graph you need:

[image]